# GetResponse method takes 21 seconds to return a response

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse, getresponse

I'm struggling with the next problem and I can't figure it out.
Tried a bunch of suggestions found on stackoverflow and other websites, but none of them changed the situation.

The Automatically detect settings from LAN Settings is unchecked. There is no proxy configured. The proxy setting of the request is set to null.

This is the code that I try to run, and regardless of the URL used, the response is returned in 21 seconds.

```
string html = string.Empty;
string url = @"https://google.com";

WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |     DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) // Takes 21 seconds to execute
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Comment: I've tested your code as it is and it executes and writes the response without delay. Unfortunately I can't start to think where the problem might be.

Comment: LE: Your answer helped quite a lot :) It's AVG that is causing the problem.
Thanks. It must be something local with my network connection, but I don't know where to start in order to find the problem. Will give it a try on a different machine connected to the same network, and eventually on a different network maybe I can find something.